# What is the RLP encoding of an address whose first byte is 0?

Tags: contract-deployment, yellow-paper, rlp, create

It's technically possible for the first byte of an address in Ethereum to be 0. If this contract then deploys another contract using the CREATE opcode, the address of the new contract will be calculated as "the rightmost 160 bits of the Keccak-256 hash of the RLP encoding of the structure containing only the sender and the account nonce" (as defined in Section 7 of the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), "Contract Creation").

Now, addresses are always 20 bytes long, but the Yellow Paper also says (in Appendix B, "Recursive Length Prefix")

> If RLP is used to encode a scalar, defined only as a non-negative integer (...), it must be encoded as the shortest byte array whose big-endian interpretation is the scalar.

If an address counts as a scalar, then it means that any leading 0 bytes must be removed before the address is RLP-encoded. This would create a corner case that is easy to overlook when trying to calculate where a contract will be deployed.

So my question has two parts:

1. Does the passage from Appendix B above apply to the sender address during the calculation of the address of a contract deployed with the CREATE opcode? Or is the address considered a plain sequence of bytes rather than a scalar?
2. Where can I find documentation supporting the answer to the above, considering that the passages I cited seem ambiguous in this matter?